# How to create default Vuex state with proper isLoading property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex, buefy

I have created actions that I dispatch directly in the store.js file in order to create a 'default' state. I have a default state property:

```
isLoading: false
```

I dispatch an action that makes multiple commits with payloads:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(axios)
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    projects: null,
    posts: null,
    isLoading: false,
    baseUrl: 'https://example.com/v2/'
  },
  getters: {

  },
  mutations: {
    SET_PROJECTS (state, payload) {
      state.projects = payload;
    },
    SET_POSTS (state, payload) {
      state.posts = payload;
    },
    IS_LOADING (state, payload) {
      state.isLoading = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setProjects ({ commit, state }) {
      let uri = `${state.baseUrl}projects`;

      commit('IS_LOADING', true);

      axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
        commit('SET_PROJECTS', response.data);
      }).finally(commit('IS_LOADING', false));
    },
    setPosts ({ commit, state }) {
      let uri = `${state.baseUrl}posts?per_page=100`;

      commit('IS_LOADING', true);

      axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
        commit('SET_POSTS', response.data);
      }).finally(commit('IS_LOADING', false));
    }
  }
})

store.dispatch('setProjects');
store.dispatch('setPosts');


export default store
```

My IS_LOADING commits seem to never happen and the mutations are not being recorded in the Vue devtools Vuex section. My SET_POSTS and SET_PROJECTS commits happen and are recorded.

I am accessing isLoading in a couple components via ...mapState and isLoading is attached to a Buefy component :

```html
<template>
  <b-notification :closable="false">
    <div v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id" class="card is-flex">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4x3">
          <img :src="project.project_image.url" alt="project image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-content is-flex">
            <p class="title is-4">{{project.title.rendered}}</p>
            <p class="subtitle is-6"></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          Phasellus nec iaculis mauris. <a>@bulmaio</a>.
          <a href="#">#css</a> <a href="#">#responsive</a>
          <br>
          <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <b-loading :is-full-page="isFullPage" :active.sync="isLoading" :can-cancel="true"></b-loading>
  </b-notification>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Projects',
  data() {
    return {
      isFullPage: false,
    }
  },
  methods: { 
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState ([
      'isLoading',
      'projects'
    ])
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>


</style>
```

The point is to render an animated loading wheel on the components that are needing the data from the api. So, why are my IS_LOADING mutations not working? Any help is appreciated.

I would like keep the dispatch calls in the store.js file. The API data is needed in multiple places within the site, so it makes sense to me to dispatch the actions in store.js.

With that I am new to Vue and Vuex, so please let me know where I am not implementing best practices.

Comment: Hello. Is there any error in browser console? e.g. `axios.get(...).finally is not a function`

Comment: No. I console logged ".finally(console.log('Reached finally'))" and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`finally` takes a function and not a value.

Your current code now immediately executes the `commit('IS_LOADING', false)` so the state never changes...

The fix is simple just use a function in your finally:

```
setProjects ({ commit, state }) {
  let uri = `${state.baseUrl}projects`;

  commit('IS_LOADING', true);

  axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
    commit('SET_PROJECTS', response.data);
  }).finally(() => commit('IS_LOADING', false));
},
```